# How to consume YUI editor events

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, yui

I think this is a simple question, but I can not find the answer

I have a rails app and I am using jquery and the YUI Rich Text Editor, I want to write some javascript/jquery to to have a minimum text length counter (i.e.  you have 240 characters left).  I have it working with a simple text-area:

```
jQuery.fn.populateCounter = function() {
    var text_length = $(this).val().length;
    var counter = $(this).siblings('p.counter');
    if (text_length == 0) {
        counter.text('Enter at least 15 characters');
    }
    else if (text_length < 15) {
        var left = 15 - text_length
        counter.text(left + ' characters to go');
    }
    else if (text_length <= 600) {
        var remaining = 600 - $(this).val().length;
        counter.text(remaining + ' characters left' );
    }
    else {
        var to_many = $(this).val().length - 600;
        counter.text(to_many + ' characters to many' );
    }
    return this;
}

$('.new_comment textarea').live('keyup',function () {
  $(this).populateCounter();
});
```

But it is unclear to me how to do it with the YUI editor (how do i consume there event? and how do i get the length of content).  Thanks for your help!

-- jt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [YAHOO.widget.SimpleEditor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.SimpleEditor.html) events. Once you have an editor created (maybe [this](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/editor/post_editor.html) is a good place to start), you could use the `editorKeyPress` event to trigger your text length check.

```
myEditor.subscribe('editorKeyPress', function () {
   var textLength = myEditor.toString().length;
   // .... do checks
});
```